# What's the purpose of this Javascript variable?

Tags: javascript

What does this do, and why is it declared this way?

```
   var shroom = 'data:image/gif;base64,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%3D%3D';
```

Comment: For future reference, questions on Stack Overflow has to be in the form of a question, not commands. You can still improve your question by providing some context like where you found this particular code snippet.

Comment: stick it in an img tag,  <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lG....">

Answer (score 7):

It represents a GIF image encoded in base 64.

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

Answer (score 0):

It's a Data URI, which is a file encoded in a URL. More info can be found on wikipedia. Here's an online tool used to create them:
http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/cgi/data/data

I believe IE doesn't have total support for Data URIs, so they're not too commonly used. If IE did, though, they'd be great for icons and small graphics embedded right into style sheets.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to encode base 64 with Javascript

[Base 64 with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-to-base64-using-javascript)